# How to make while loop work inbetween time interval?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to create a nested while loop which should be working in hours 02:20 - 21:50, butI can't figure out the boolean expression which would fulfill the condition.

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print((now.hour >= 2 and now.minute >= 20), (now.hour <= 21 and now.minute <= 49))
    while (now.hour >= 2 and now.minute >= 20) and (now.hour <= 21 and now.minute <= 49):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

This is my code, unfortunately it doesn't work.
For example if the current hour is 17:50 the nested while loop will stop working because `now.minute = 50` and is greater than `49`. This is what I've realised while testing it rn.
Perhaps the first part  of the condition is also flawled in the same way.

How can I make the loop work between 02:20:00(a.m.) till 21:49:59(9:49:59 p.m.)?

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
switch = !(2 <= now.hour <= 21) : True ? (20 <= now.minute <= 49)
while (2 <= now.hour <= 21) and switch:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Wait, unfortunately it is flawled in similar way to mine.
The admissable values of minutes are in between range (20; 49). 
I need the while loop to work between hours 2:20 to 21:50 due to this fact I the loop needs to work at 03:01, 03:02, ... 03:19, 03:50, 03:51, .... etc.
And this condition make this unachievable.

Comment: I understand now. Try this code, it should work as you say

Comment: Is that python?

Comment: Yes it is. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to do it. I used the `.replace()` method of the datetime object to prevent setting the datetime objects' day, month, year values explicitly.

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    start_time.replace(hour=2, minute=20)
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    end_time.replace(hour=21, minute=50)
    while start_time < now < end_time:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
```